# Using Nodejs unstable alongside stable to access ES6/Harmony

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

I wanted to start practicing ES6, and plan to do that using Node.js (--harmony) in the first instance. I have the stable 0.10 branch on my Ubuntu computer already and want to run the unstable version just for testing new coding styles.

Is there a way of running a node 0.11 instance locally to a project (i.e. from node-modules?), or some other best practice?

Or, as this is a development machine anyway, perhaps I could just replace stable Node with unstable anyway as it is now 'stable enough'?

Comment: What operating system are you using? In Windows it's just a matter of running `Node.exe` of the correct version

Comment: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Thanks vkurchatkin. That worked

Answer (score 1):

1. Install some node version manager: [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) or [nvm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm). For example, let's install `n`:

   ```
   $ sudo npm install -g n
   ```
2. Install node version you want to use for your project. For expamle, 0.11.14:

   ```
   $ sudo n 0.11.14
   ```
3. Add `scripts start` command to your `package.json`:

   ```
   {
       "name": "some-project",
       "version": "0.1.0",
       "scripts": {
           "start": "n use 0.11.14 ."
       }
   }
   ```
4. Run your project from project folder:

   ```
   npm start
   ```
5. Enjoy:)

Comment: Also to manage versions exists https://github.com/riywo/ndenv based on Ruby's rbenv.